# Visual studio code with cmake on Windows, how to set compiler and debug configuration

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-code, cmake, mingw

I have Windows 7 with few different versions of Visual Studio and MinGW. When I create a cmake project and open it in Visual Studio Code it get configured automatically to use Visual Studio 14 compiler, I also have Visual Studio 17 and 19 installed, version 17 have `"Desktop development with C++" workload.` installed.

I would like to know how to set which compiler to use when running initial configuration (when build folder is empty) and how to create a debug configuration. When I run plain debug button that do not require the configuration the break point do not trigger.

I have tried with these config files in launch.json

```
"version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${command:cmake.launchTargetPath}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "env": {
                "Path": "${env:Path};D:\\Installation\\oracClient 19\\instantclient_19_14\\" 
            },
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "c:\\Users\\marko.grujic.CHIP\\.vscode\\extensions\\ms-vscode.cpptools-1.8.4\\debugAdapters\\bin\\WindowsDebugLauncher.exe",
            "logging": {
                "engineLogging": true
            },
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                },
                {
                    "description":  "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
                    "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        },

        
        
        {
            "name": "(Windows) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${command:cmake.launchTargetPath}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "environment": [],
            "env": {
                "Path": "${env:Path};D:\\Installation\\oracClient 19\\instantclient_19_14\\" 
            },
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "logging": {
                "engineLogging": true
            },
            "console": "externalTerminal"
        }
    ]
```

Non of these work, `(gdb) Launch` config do not work because the code was compiled with Visual Studio compiler and I am trying to use MinGW debugger (This is assumption).
`(Windows) Launch` also do not work but I have no idea why, it does run indefinitely but none of breakpoints work.

Comment: Install the [cmake plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cmake-tools), it configures everything for you and even has an option to debug a target so you don't need to use `launch.json` either (if you don't need to customise launch arguments)

Comment: @AlanBirtles I do have that Plugin and when I click on run->addConfiguration I get to chose between multiple options and non of them work for me. Also the plugin actually create a entry in launch.json config file. The issue with the autogenerate configuration is that I get an error message that miDebuggerPath is not set, and when I do set it it either hangs or failed to launch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change a compiler I recommend:

1. deleting the build folder.
2. From visual studio code press f1 and run: `CMake: scan for kits`.
3. f1 and run: `CMake: select a kit`.

On step number 3 you will be asked to select a compiler version.